# GitHub Actions Workflow - Published Nuget Package Always marked as pre-release

Tags: c#, github, continuous-integration, nuget, github-actions

I am publishing a Nuget package from a GitHub Actions Workflow (.yml file listed below) to GitHub Packages.

**C# Project file PropertyGroup:**

As shown below the project's`.csproj` file does not contain a value for `VersionSuffix`:

```xml
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>
    <VersionPrefix>1.4.0</VersionPrefix>
    <Version>1.4.0</Version>
    <PackageVersion>1.4.0</PackageVersion>
    <VersionSuffix></VersionSuffix>
    <InformationalVersion>This is a package.</InformationalVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

**GitHub Actions Workflow .yml File:**

```
name: Build, Pack, Publish

on: [push]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: windows-latest
    steps:

    - uses: actions/checkout@v1

    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 2.2.109

    - name: dotnet build
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release

    - name: Install NuGet client
      uses: warrenbuckley/Setup-Nuget@v1

    - name: Add private GitHub registry to NuGet
      run: nuget sources add -name "GPR" -Source https://nuget.pkg.github.com/Operator9/index.json -Username Operator9 -Password ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

    - name: Pack
      run: dotnet pack -c Release -o out

    - name: Push generated package to GitHub registry
      run: nuget push .\out\*.nupkg -Source "GPR" -SkipDuplicate
```

**Problem:**

Everything in the workflow executes fine except the package is always considered `prerelease`.

**Testing Method 1:**

When I visit this URL my package is only listed if I change `prerelease=false` to `prerelease=true`

`https://nuget.pkg.github.com/Operator9/query?q=MyPackageName&prerelease=false`

**Testing Method 2:**

The same behavior exists from within Visual Studio Nuget Package Manager.  The package is only visible if I check "Include prerelease".

Comment: The discussion [here](https://github.community/t5/GitHub-Actions/Package-listed-as-prerelease/td-p/40548) seems to suggest that it's a client-side problem. Have you tried clearing the cache from the NuGet Package Manager options?

Comment: I just noticed you are testing via the `nuget.pkg.github.com` URL though, so that does suggest it's server-side.

Answer (score 1):

There's some minimal properties that you must specify inside the `<PropertyGroup>` tag on your csproj.

```
<PackageId>AppLogger</PackageId>
<Version>1.0.0</Version>
<Authors>your_name</Authors>
<Company>your_company</Company>
```

Looks like you need PackageId, Authors and Company.